# Having trouble executing SQL statement

Tags: sql-server-2005

I keep getting an "IDENTIFIER expected" error when trying to execute the following code.  Can anyone help with this?

```
SELECT @remotesql = '
SELECT A.AS_OF_DATE, A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, A.MARKET_VALUE, A.CUSIP, A.SECURITY_TYPE, C.ADMIN_OFFICER, C.BRANCH_NUMBER, 
       D.TICKER_SYMBOL, D.SUB_CLASS,
CASE
    WHEN C.ACCT_SUB_TYPE = 126 OR C.ACCT_SUB_TYPE = 128 OR C.ACCT_SUB_TYPE = 130 OR
         C.ACCT_SUB_TYPE = 131 THEN ''AMGIC/Outside Custodian''
    WHEN B.AUTHORITY = ''N'' THEN ''CUSTODY''
    ELSE ''AUM''
END AS ACCOUNT_TYPE
FROM [DPG].[dbo].[AddvHoldings] AS A
LEFT JOIN SQLUser.AC_IV AS B ON A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = B.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN SQLUser.AC_BI AS C ON A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = C.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN Addv.Holdings AS D ON A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = D.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AND A.CUSIP = D.CUSIP_NUMBER
'

SELECT @localsql  = 'select * from openquery (TRP, ' +
    dbo.quotestring(@remotesql) + ')'

SELECT @insertsql = 'INSERT INTO #1Holdings'

SET @insertsql = @insertsql + ' ' + @localsql


EXEC(@insertsql)
```

Comment: Have you tried executing the embedded SQL separately (to narrow down the cause of the issue)?

Comment: As @m.edmondson recommends - I find it much easier to write the SQL directly, and once it's working, then turn it into dynamic SQL

Comment: @freefaller - Or avoid dynamic SQL all together

Comment: That is certainly the best solution @m.edmondson, but unfortunately not always possible

Comment: @freefaller - Unfortunately so